# Why in URLRequest use "setValue: forHTTPHeaderField:"

Tags: ios, nsmutableurlrequest, urlrequest

I use GET/POST request in app, and in some example i see:

```
    [URLRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [URLRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Can you explain the significance of these tapes.

Comment: Do you know what is HTTP Header ?

Comment: Yes, i read for it.
More information can read in wiki.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Comment: I am not php developer and i dont read documentation. I did not know propertyes what can contains in the Header. But now i read several articles and understood some nuances.